# Chrome Android drops frames for no reason while scrolling

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I found scrolling performance on Chrome Android is so terrible. If you slide down the page with your finger not leaving the screen to perform a scroll action you'll notice obvious stutters/jitters (even if no dom has changed). Removing all relevant event listeners doesn't make a difference. So I tried to capture a performance record to figure out the problem but found nothing useful.

You can see in the following screenshot, "Others" cost so much time. I've googled for a long time to find what does that "Others" mean in the Summary tab but failed to find any information about it. Those "Others" almost occupied the whole timeline, but I don't know if it's related to those stutters. I tried to open the same webpage in an app's webview (don't know which Chrome version it uses) and did not find any stutters.

Example screenshot

[image]

Chrome Version: 61(stable)/64(dev and Canary)

Android Version: 8.0

Device: Google Pixel

Comment: Could be due to a bug in Chrome. See if it's fixed in Chrome Canary.

Comment: @wOxxOm I've tested Chrome Dev and Chrome Canary both have this issue...